# Choosing Vds and id values for a Power MOSFET

Tags: power, mosfet

I have a question regarding the choice of an appropiate power MOSFET in relation to the circuit below. What are the safety margins that I need to look for.

For example, Vdd = 100V and I = 5A. Obviously, buying a transistor with Vds = 100V and id = 5A is not a good ideea. What do you suggest the % safety margin is? And just a quick stupid question, Vds has to be greater than 100V, not 50V, right?

MOSFET is in saturation region, acting as a switch. (output is either Vdd or GND).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzwsqc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During switching, voltage spikes will occur.

Factors which make spikes worse:

- fast switching
- inductive load (incl. wiring)
- bad layout with long, inductive traces
- LC ringing
- Load back-EMF if you use a motor as brake

This should be kept in mind when picking a MOSFET. For a 100V load, a 130-150V MOSFET should be adequate.

This document explains MOSFET avalanche breakdown on overvoltage:

http://www.vishay.com/docs/90160/an1005.pdf

Keep in mind that fast voltage spikes can also exceed maximum Vgs limit, which is usually pretty low. The very thin gate oxide layer is fragile and will be punctured almost instantly if Vgs spikes above the limit. This can happen on a burst of parasitic oscillations, for example.

Now, the current rating.

Usually, you don't select a FET based on current rating alone. Rather, you'd set a target for the maximum allowed dissipation, and this gives you a maximum RdsON value. Then, you decide on a compromise between RdsON and Qg which controls switching losses, with an aim to minimize total losses (resistive + switching).

Most likely, the FET you will select will have a current rating well above the current you will actually use, and what limits the current will be its maximum dissipation, which depends on how you cool it.

Keep it in mind for short-circuit protection, though.

Comment: Thank you for you very good response. It explains everything I wanted to know. Just one more quick question that is still not clear to me. For my particular circuit, the load is 100V or 50V? I'm thinking that if the resistive load is connected in regards to GND, the circuit will not work, so the load is actually 50V.

Comment: On your circuit, if one FET is ON, then the other will have the full Vdd on it. Therefore both FET should be rated for full Vdd plus safety margin. If the load is between output and GND, then it will see Vdd or 0V depending on which MOSFET is ON. I don't get how you get your 50V...

Comment: My mistake. I wanted to say in case the output is in regards to 50V, not GND.

Comment: Last question, I promise. What if this circuit is just 1/3 of this circuit. https://d3i5bpxkxvwmz.cloudfront.net/resized/images/remote/http_s.eeweb.com/articles/2015/05/21/3-Phase-Bridge-MOSFET-Power-Module-1432200906_400_250.png (Three phase inverter for example). The Vds rating should still be for 100V?

Comment: I don't understand about the 50V thing. For the three phase, same as above, you got three pairs of FETs, and each one has full supply voltage across it when the other is ON. So, all should be rated for full supply voltage.